# Japanese novels 上・下

Tags: kanji

I have a couple of Japanese novels and textbooks that have the kanji 上　＆　下 on them. Now, intuitively, I would say that the 下 kanji would be the book I start with. Whereas the 上 would be the one I finish up with. But I'm not sure.

This is an example of what I'm asking about:

[image]

Where do I begin? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The opposite is true: 上篇{じょうへん} is the first volume and 下篇{げへん} is the second, corresponding to the traditional writing direction.

If there's a third volume, they will be labelled 上、中、下 in order.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if there's a fourth volume?

Comment: If there's a fourth volume, I think the series will be numbered.

Comment: Definitely 編  ＞ 篇  for the purpose of Japanese-as-a-foreign-language..

Comment: 「上巻・下巻」もありますよね。。

Answer (score 1):

I often find that novels that I'm familiar with here in the US are split up in to 2 or 3 parts, leading to these 上 and 下 volumes.  Patrick Rothfuss has a great [blog entry](http://blog.patrickrothfuss.com/2011/11/fanmail-faq-why-are-they-breaking-up-your-book) as to why this happens.  His example involves German to English translations, which he says are 30% - 40% longer, and I believe the same is true for Japanese translations.  Once books get to a certain size, they get really hard to bind durably so that they don't physically fall apart.

Comment: Smaller books are also easier to read on the train :-)

Comment: That is very interesting.